# Merging multiple iOS apps with a menu system

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, core-data

I have several small utility apps for iOS. I want to combine these into one app with each utility accessed from a menu. I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this. The apps use Core Data which makes things slightly more complicated. Are there any standard ways of doing this or is just a matter of glueing pieces together until I get it to work?

Thanks

Comment: You can certainly manage multiple core data stacks in one app.  Question is, is it worth it?  It's hard enough to manage one.

Answer (score 0):

I recently worked on one such application. The design was as follows

-> Each sub application registers with the container app by providing the name of it's app delegate. I'd maintained a plist for this purpose which holds a mapping of the app name and the appDelegate class.

-> Whenever the user selects an app the container app will instantiate the app delegate and add the main view controller returned by it as the root view controller.

This design helps solve the logical part of the problem. You will still have a hard time before compiling all the source code as a single project.

As far as core data is concerned you must not have a hard time with it if each of your sub application uses a different object store.